# Can I use a custom Websocket Connection with Chromecast?

Tags: websocket, webrtc, chromecast

I have set a websocket connection with my Chromecast to stream my computer screen but the video has and high latency and very poor frames. I am using a video object and not the player from the Chromecast SDK.

I am able to connect and share SDP and Offer, candidates and establish a connection but I am not sure if I am doing it well. Or If I have to use a Channel from the Chromecast SDK to set the WebRTC connection.

I use my own server with node.js running in my computer for the signaling.

Thanks

This is the code to connect to the Chromecast via WebSocket.
It is a local connection without stun  servers.

const signaling = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.35:8008');

```
signaling.onopen = () => {

    log('You are now connected!');

    const peerConnection = createPeerConnection(signaling);

    addMessageHandler(signaling, peerConnection);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Chromecast doesn't allow more than 15 fps if you are using a custom web app.
WebRTC for mirroring the desktop has the same fps as I get with my custom app and WebRTC connection.